# Splitting a list within a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

How can I make a function to return the lowest number in a list like:

```
listA = [[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]]
```

I want it to return 10

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Flatten the list by using `itertools.chain`, then find the minimum as you would otherwise:

```
from itertools import chain

listA = [[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]]
min(chain.from_iterable(listA))
# 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> listA = [[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]]
>>> min(y for x in listA for y in x)
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `result` to `float("inf")`. Iterate over every number in every list and call each number `i`. If `i` is less than `result`, `result = i`. Once you're done, `result` will contain the lowest value.

Comment: This is one way to do it, but not the python way.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using list comprehension

```
>>> listA = [[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]]
>>> output = [y for x in listA for y in x]
>>> min(output)
10
```